# Angular 2 Tutorial on OS X El Capitan Returns "Cannot GET /" in browser

Tags: angularjs, node.js, typescript, angular, osx-elcapitan

I'm trying to get through the Angular 2 with TypeScript on OS X. I have followed the tutorial and received no errors when compiled. The `npm start` command completed successfully and a new tab was displayed in Safari. The address is `http://localhost:3000` the only thing that showed was

> Cannot GET /

I am not familiar with Lite-Server and I don't know if I've failed to start something to get the tutorial running.

Is there something I've missed or some way to determine if the Lite-Server is running?

Comment: Can you please provide link to tutorial or more details?

Comment: Sorry about that:  https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your folder/file structure might be confusing lite-server.

lite-server will look for a bs-config.json file.  This should be at the same level as your node_modules folder.

[Here is the github page for lite-servier](https://github.com/johnpapa/lite-server).

> For example, to change the server port, watched file paths, and base
>   directory for your project, create a  bs-config.json  in your
>   project's folder:

bs-config.json

```
{
  "port": 8000,
  "files": ["./src/**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick. I had to modify the file a bit from the github page. For anyone who needs this in the future set the bs-config.json port to "3000" and replace "src" with "app". Thanks.