# Angular2 parameter URL not working when visited directly

Tags: typescript, angular, angular2-routing

I have configured Angular2 routes with parameters. When I visit `/censo/119` or `/viaje/119` from one of the `[routerLink]` I've defined it works fine. But when I go directly to the url `http://localhost:3000/censo/119` I get a 404.

I'm using `lite-server` for my development app.

Am I missing a configuration? Do I need to use a different server?

This is my `app.routes.ts`

```
const routes: RouterConfig = [
  { path: '', component: CensoComponent },
  { path: 'censo', component: CensoComponent },
  { path: 'viajes', component: ViajesComponent },
  { path: 'censo/:viaje', component: CensoDetailComponent },
  { path: 'viajes/:viaje', component: ViajesDetailComponent },
];
```

And this are my routerLinks

```
<a [routerLink]="['/censo']">Censo</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/viajes']">Viajes</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/censo',119]">Censo 119</a>
<a [routerLink]="['/viajes',119]">Viaje 119</a>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**EDIT**

I've added a `bs-config.json` but I'm getting the same behavior.

```
{
    "port": 8000,
    "files": ["./**/*.{html,htm,css,js}"],
    "server": { "baseDir": "." }
}
```

This is what I get in the browser.
[image: May it has something to do with systemjs?]

And this is my project structure, in case it helps.

[image: ./]

[image: ./app]

Thanks

Comment: Your routes look fine.  Please see my answer on this post.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38209427/angular-2-tutorial-on-os-x-el-capitan-returns-cannot-get-in-browser/38209590#38209590

Comment: When you visit link from `routerLink` which url is in the browser?

Comment: @AleksandrM it's `http://localhost:3000/viajes/119`

Comment: @NickAcosta Thanks. I've added a `bs-config.json` but I get the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

You should run the `lite-server` command from the same location as your `index.html`. The default behavior serves content from the current folder, opens the browser, and applies an HTML5 fallback to `index.html`.

If you for some reason cannot execute the command from that folder and your `index.html` resides in a `src` map which is a child of the folder where you execute the lite-server from, you should add a `bs-config.json` file with a `server` and `baseUrl` property like this:

```
{
  "server": { "baseDir": "./src" }
}
```

And run the lite-server like this, depending on the filename of your config, and on the location:

```
lite-server -c ./bs-config.json
```

Comment: I am running it as `npm run lite-server` and my `package.json` and `index.html` are in the same folder. Do I need anything else in the `index.html` besides `<base href="/">`? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks. I've added a `bs-config.json` but I'm getting the same behavior.